# Is there an easy way of creating s3 bucket with coldfusion?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, coldfusion

I have tried a few ways of doing that but can't get it done. I used coldfusion AWS wrapper but with no luck. And I can't get any useful information from google. The only way I'm thinking I can do it is to call AWS REST java API through coldfusion which sounds really complicated. And i don't know where to start. Can somebody at least give me some code that does bucket creation?

The first one i will show the coldfusion aws s3 wrapper code what i was using. github.com/joedanz/cf-amazon-s3 And other code which is much simpler but does'nt work because of cfdirectory is getting local paths only. pastebin.com/Sai8zwhX.

For first I'm editing access key and secret key so I think that's all what I should edit. And I'm receiving - Please check your AWS credentials at top of script: /aws/s3test.cfm But im sure that the credentials are right.

Thank you

Comment: Could you post any scripts/code you have tried so far?

Comment: The first one i will show the coldfusion aws s3 wrapper code what i was using.

https://github.com/joedanz/cf-amazon-s3

And other code which is much simpler but does'nt work because of cfdirectory is getting local paths only.

http://pastebin.com/Sai8zwhX

Thank you

Comment: For first I'm editing access key and secret key so I think that's all what I should edit. And I'm receiving - Please check your AWS credentials at top of script: /aws/s3test.cfm

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39947798/edit) and include 1) what code you have tried 2) the result of that code (error message, etc...) 3) what you expected to happen instead.